# Progress Dialog impossible to show using one AsyncTask class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progressdialog

I'm trying to show one Progress Dialog inside my MainActivity but is impossible:
This class is inside My MainActivity:

```
   class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private String titulo;
        private String mensaje;
        private MainActivity activity;
        public MyAsyncTask(MainActivity activity){
            this.activity = activity;

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            this.activity.createDirs();
            this.activity.copyAssets();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            this.progressDialog.setTitle("test");
            this.progressDialog.setMessage("test message...");
            this.progressDialog.show();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OPA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

This code is inside My MainActivity.java: Basically when the user press one button I'm creating one reference to my MyAsyncTask and executing it.

```
btnInit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(flag==1){
                    myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(new MainActivity());
                    myAsyncTask.execute();
                    try {
                        myAsyncTask.get();
                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Dashboardactivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    flag=0;
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
```

The code of the method `doInBackground()` of the class `MyAsyncTask` is being executed without problems. I will appreciate any idea guys, thanks so much.

Comment: `AsyncTask` and `ProgressDialog` are both deprecated; please consider not using them. Beyond that, get rid of `myAsyncTask.get()` and move the code after it into `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: how long to take the doInBackground function? I tested your code with `Thread.sleep(5000)` and it works correctly just try with `Thread.sleep()` to check if the problem is in the doInBackGround method or not

Comment: Hi @ShayKin and  @CommonsWare thanks  for your comments.. doInBackground takes about 5 seconds these functions are creating a directory into the sdcard and copy all my files from my assets folder to a folder..when it finish the Toast from the `onPreExecute` only is showing..

Comment: @ShayKin I did it  `myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(new MainActivity());
                    myAsyncTask.execute();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(8000);` but is not showing.. is very strange Here is my full code: https://pastebin.com/tEJsjebM please check it.. thank so much.

Comment: i will take look

Comment: add the thread.sleep() inside the doInBackgroun int you class MyAsynTask

Comment: I added it: https://imgur.com/a/lIsHaT5 but don't appear.. Very strange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230491/discussion-between-shay-kin-and-freddy-daniel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thread is blocked, when you call `myAsyncTask.get()` that's why your Progress Dialog is not displayed so remove the `myAsyncTask.get()` and add those line on `onPostExecute`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Dashboardactivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

full code :

```
  btnInit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(flag==1){
                        myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(new MainActivity());
                        myAsyncTask.execute();
  
                        flag=0;
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
                    }
                }
```

and on your asyncTask :

```
   class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private String titulo;
        private String mensaje;
        private MainActivity activity;
        public MyAsyncTask(MainActivity activity){
            this.activity = activity;

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            this.activity.createDirs();
            this.activity.copyAssets();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            this.progressDialog.setTitle("test");
            this.progressDialog.setMessage("test message...");
            this.progressDialog.show();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OPA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Dashboardactivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi @Shay Kin thanks for your answer. I did what you say.. now the Toast from the onPreExecute is being showing very fast but still the progress dialog don't appear. I don't know what is happening exactly. I'm using also opencv and tesseract library

Comment: We conclude that the two methodds `createDirs();` and `copyAssets();` inside of `doInBackground()` method are causing the problem. The code of @Shay Kin works perfectly.